# What does monit consider to be memory usage?

Tags: memory, memory-usage, monit

Once can have monit monitor memory usage…

```
check system foo
  if memory usage > 95% then alert
```

Does it use free RAM, or free -/+ buffers/cache? (or something else?)

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           998        851        146          0        114         70
-/+ buffers/cache:        666        332
Swap:         2047         54       1993
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be get from the source of monit https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit/tree/master/process.

For linux the value is computed in [sysdep_LINUX.c](https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit/blob/master/process/sysdep_LINUX.c) and comes from /proc/meminfo :

```
si->total_mem_kbyte = systeminfo.mem_kbyte_max - mem_free - buffers - cached;
```

In other words monit use as memory usage MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached.

In your case 998 - 146 - 114 - 70 = 668

Answer (score 1):

On latest Monit (ie: 5.25.x) the `memory usage` value accounts for ZFS ARC cache - so if someout is using ZFS, used memory is not ballooned by reclaimable ARC data.

Current memory usage is calculated as:

```
si->memory.usage.bytes = systeminfo.memory.size - zfsarcsize -
(uint64_t)(mem_free + buffers + cached + slabreclaimable) * 1024;
```

See [here](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/src/b12dc2ace690522e7a2c97255a33cfa49ab09d2d/src/process/sysdep_LINUX.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#sysdep_LINUX.c-455) from more details.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, it based on:

```
used memory - cached = 851 - 70 = 781
```

Comment: any documentation for that?